# I have setted TextButtonThemeData, but not working

Tags: flutter, dart, themes

I made Theme of TextButtonThemeData in main.dart file but It was not applying text color.
I checked API DOC, primary property manage overall color except for backgroundColor.
but still can not change text color to be white

**main.dart**

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
    
    theme: ThemeData(
      textButtonTheme: TextButtonThemeData(
        style: TextButton.styleFrom(
          backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
          primary: Colors.white,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
          ),
          minimumSize: Size(400, 60),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    
    initialRoute: "/login",
    routes: {
      "/login": (context) => LoginPage(),
      "/home": (context) => const HomePage(),
    })}
```

**Custom_form.dart**

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Column(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
  children: [
    Text(text),
    const SizedBox(height: small_gap),
    TextFormField(
      validator: (value) =>
          value!.isEmpty ? "Please enter some text" : null,
      obscureText: text == "Password" ? true : false,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: "Enter $text",
          enabledBorder:
              OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12)),
          focusedBorder:
              OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12)),
          errorBorder:
              OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12)),
          focusedErrorBorder:
              OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12))),
    )
  ],
);}
```

**OUTPUT**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zcks.png)

I expected the `textColor` of `TextButton` is White, but it is black.

How To change the color of the text.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ButtonStyle` and use the `foregroundColor` property to assign `color` to the `text`

```
        textButtonTheme: TextButtonThemeData(
              style: ButtonStyle(
            backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.teal),
            textStyle: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
            shape: MaterialStateProperty.all(RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12))),
            minimumSize: MaterialStateProperty.all(const Size(400, 60)),
            foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.white),
          ))
```

Comment: Thank you, Jain
I solved the problem with first answer.
but I tried second answer but not working and error generatedT^T